# How to display promise/observable with value 0 in Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a promise `role$: Promise<Role>` where `Role` is an enum with several values (`ROLE1`, `ROLE2` etc.).

I want to display the value of `role$` in my template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="authService.role$ | async as role">
  {{role}} <!-- only displayed if role is > 0 -->
</ng-container>
```

My problem is that even though the promise holds a value, as soon as it is 0 (the first enum `ROLE1`), the `*ngIf` condition will still be false and the contents will not be displayed. I know that I could set custom values to the enums starting at 1 but there must be a better solution than that? Is there a way to bind `role$` to `role` without using `*ngIf`?

Comment: I think that your best bet is to use custom non falsy value for enums. Or maybe use field instead of async pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to extract value from `async` pipe and then use it:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{bar: authService.role$ | async} as foo">
    {{ foo.bar }}
</ng-container>
```

So after resolving promise you can do what you want.

Comment: Neat trick with wrapping it into an object.

Comment: Definitely a neat trick as @Antoniossss notes, but it shouldn't be necessary. Angular needs to regularize its syntax because it's very counterintuitive that you need to do anything like this at all